# $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n x^n$ and there exists a sequence $x_n\to 0$, such that $f(x_n)=0$, for all $n$. Then $f\equiv 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

I found this question really difficult for me, I don't even know how to start with it? Could you help me? I will appreciate that.

> Prove that if $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n x^n$ (defined in $(-R,R)$) and there exists a sequence $(x_n)$, with $x_n \neq 0$ for all $n$, tending to $0$ such that $f(x_n)=0$ for all $n$, then $f(x)=0$ for all $x$.

Thank you! :)

Comment: The zeros of a non-constant analytic function are isolated.

Comment: @booksee that is equivalent to the question asked

Answer (score 5):

First of all, since $f$ is continuous, $f(0) = 0$, so $a_0 = 0$.

Now, think about $f(x)/x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n+1}x^n$, which is again continuous. For any $x_n$, we have $f(x_n)/x_n = 0$, so $f(x)/x \rightarrow 0$, as $x \rightarrow 0$. Hence, $a_1 = 0$.

Continuing this way, we show that $a_n = 0$ for all $n$.

Note that we need to assume that all $x_n$ are distinct from $0$.

Comment: Thank you! Why is this sentence true 'For any $x_n$, we have $f(x_n)/x_n = 0$'?

Comment: Since we assumed $f(x_n) = 0$.

Comment: what if $x_n$ goes to zero faster than $f(x_n)$?

Comment: We are not talking about $f(x_n)/x_n \rightarrow 0$. We are stating that since $f(x_n) = 0$ and $x_n \neq 0$, $f(x_n)/x_n = 0$.

Comment: Alright. Why does it imply that "$f(x)/x \rightarrow 0$, as $x \rightarrow 0$"?

Comment: Since $f(x)/x$ is a power series, it must be continuous on its domain. We now have a sequence $(x_n)$ approaching $0$ for which $f(x_n)/x_n = 0$. By the definition of continuity, we get $f(x)/x \rightarrow 0$, since $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(x_n)/x_n = 0$.

Answer (score 3):

By continuity of $f$ we have that $\,f(0)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=0$.

As $f\in C^\infty(-R,R)$, there exist $y_n\in(x_{n+1},x_n)$, such that 
$$
0=\frac{f(x_{n+1})-f({x_n})}{x_{n+1}-x_n}=f'(y_n),
$$ 
due to Mean Value Theorem.

Clearly $y_n\to 0$, and due to continuiuty of $f'$, we have $f'(0)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f'(y_n)=0$.

Similarly, we may found a sequence $\{z_n\}$, with $z_n\to 0$, and $f''(z_n)=0$,
and hence $f''(0)=0$.

Recursively, we obtain that $\,f^{(n)}(0)=0$, for all $n$, which implies that $a_n=0$, for all $n$, and hence $f\equiv 0$.

Comment: Why did you equate $f'(y_n)$ to 0 in the second line?

Comment: Because $f(x_{n+1})=f({x_n})=0$, and hence $f(x_{n+1})-f({x_n})=0$, as well.

Comment: You tacitly assumed here that the coefficients $a_n$ are real.

Comment: @AlexM. Not necessarily. Define $g=\mathrm{Re}\,f$ and $h=\mathrm{Im}\,f$. Then, using the same argument, one obtains that $h=g=0$.

Answer (score 3):

If $f(x)$ is not identically $0$, some $a_n$ is nonzero.  Suppose $a_m$ is the first nonzero coefficient.  Then $g(x) = f(x)/x^m = a_m + a_{m+1} x + \ldots$ is a convergent power series, therefore continuous, and $g(0) = a_m \ne 0$.
By continuity, there is $\epsilon > 0$ such that $g(x) \ne 0$ for $|x| < \epsilon$, and thus $f(x) \ne 0$ for $0 < |x| < \epsilon$.